# Background-image + Making a Div into a link

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, background-image

I created a small box which I placed at the bottom right of the map and would like it to have the facebook logo as the background image and make the div clickable so that it directs you to the site. I tried adding this to the code but cannot seem to get either the fb image nor the link to work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jw5VV/)

CSS (Background Image):

```
      #facebook {    
        background-image: url(http://www.ridersmatch.com/Facebook_logo.png); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        background:#fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
```

JQUERY (Click Function):

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push($('<div id="infowindow"/>')[0]);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push($('<div id="facebook"/>')[0]);

    $('#facebook').click(function() {
         window.open('http://www.facebook.com');        
    });
```

Comment: If you want link _functionality_, then you should use an `a` in the first place instead of a `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jw5VV/1/ Within jsfiddle, make sure you rightclick on the facebook link and choose "open in new tab/page".

The problem is that you're first setting the `background-image`, and then set the `background` to `#fff`. Only the last style is then applied.

Also, since your background picture is quite large, you need to specify the `background-size`.

Use this css:

```
#facebook {    
    background-image: url(http://www.ridersmatch.com/Facebook_logo.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
      }
```

To make that facebook-logo clickable, wrap it with an `anchor` like so:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">
    <div id="facebook"></div>
</a>
```

You could also spare the facebook `div` and apply the `#facebook` id to the `anchor` directly.

Either way, you won't need the javascript/jQuery click function.

Check the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jw5VV/1/

Comment: Thanks! Is it just a jsfiddle thing or would you normally still be able to left-click on the box to open the link? Also, when you say apply the #facebook id directly to the anchor, how would you code it? Something like this? _map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push($('<a href="#facebook"></a>')[0]);_

Comment: About the clicking: if you added `target="_blank"` to the anchor, the link would open in a new tab, even from within jsfiddle. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jw5VV/2/). Add an id to any tag like so: `<tag id="yourID"></tag>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really need to learn how to use html/css. I only just started coding a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just have the link inside the div and set the css style of the anchor to fill the div

css

```
#facebook a { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }
```

html

```
<div id="facebook">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com"></a>
</div>
```